# How to post both a javascript variable and a html form via $.ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I posted two javascript variables to a php file aswell as a html form using Ajax separately. I want to use the two javascript variables with the posted form values but I'm not sure how to go about this.

```js
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var aucid = "<?php echo $auctionID; ?>";
      var userid = "<?php echo $userID; ?>";
  $.ajax({
    url: "JqueryPHP/HighestBid.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {'auctionid': aucid, 'userid' : userid },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#price').html(result);
    }
});


  $('form').bind('submit', function (event) {

 
event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 



          $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
            url: 'JqueryPHP/HighestBid.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
        
        
  });
```

I posted the two javascript variables separately  to the form.

```html
<form> 

<input type="number" min="<?php echo $startingprice ?>" step="any" style="width: 10em;" size="35" name="newbid" id="newbid" tabindex="1" class="form-control"  placeholder="New Bid €" value="" required>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="2" class="form-control btn btn-login" style="width: 14em" value="submit">
                                     
 </form>
```

```html
<h4 class="price">Highest bid : <span id="price"></span></h4>
```

When I echo the value of userID into the span class, you can see it has a value of 2.

[image]

```html
//JqueryPHP/HighestBid.php'

$auctionid;
$userID;

  $auctionid = $_POST['auctionid'];
  $userID = $_POST['userid'];
  echo $userID;
  
  
  if (isset($_POST['newbid'])) 
  {
  $newbid=$_POST['newbid'];
 
  
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'auctionsite');
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO auction (useridhighestbid)VALUES("'.$userID.'")';
 if(@$conn->query($sql)){  //execute the query and check it worked    
                            return TRUE;
                        } 
         
  }
```

however when I try use the userID when the form is submitted and try insert it into the database for testing purposes, the value is 0.

How would I go about posting the form value with the javascript variables so I can use an update statement to update my database?

[image]

Comment: you can append `aucid` and `userid`  value in `Form Serialize`.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? It seems to me that `userid` would already be stored in the session and `aucid` is determined by the url that is visited. Using user-provided values only opens your auction to manipulation by the client.

Comment: I addressed this issue as well @jeroen but some people just don't care it seems...

Comment: @will mannix see updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set two hidden inputs to save `aucid` and `userid` like this:

```
<form> 

<input type="number" min="<?php echo $startingprice ?>" step="any" style="width: 10em;" size="35" name="newbid" id="newbid" tabindex="1" class="form-control"  placeholder="New Bid €" value="" required>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="2" class="form-control btn btn-login" style="width: 14em" value="submit">

        <input name='aucid' style="display:none"/>  
        <input name='userid' style="display:none"/>                                                        
 </form>





<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("input[name='aucid']").val("<?php echo $auctionID; ?>");
          $("input[name='userid']").val("<?php echo $userID; ?>");

          .......................
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I usually wouldn't recommend the use of hidden fields, since it can be edited client side. Those 2 variables should be handled server side, i.e. be set as php session variables. Otherwise, it's too easy to "do things that you are not supposed to do".

Comment: @Martin I think write it like him witch `var aucid = "<?php echo $auctionID; ?>";` will also be seen.

Comment: Yes, but might as well point out the dangers with the use, and discourage the use of it, since it does create a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you parsed the variables correctly, you can use:

`$_POST['JavaScript_variable_name_goes_here'];`

or

`$_GET['JavaScript_variable_name_goes_here'];`

to retrieve the variables in a PHP format, depending on your AJAX method.

A direct example from your AJAX function would be:

```
<?php $auctionId=$_POST['auctionid']; ?>
```

However, what I would encourage you to do, is that once a user is logged in, you set their userId as a session variable that you can use wherever the user "goes". That way, you are not parsing a *crucial* data element through JavaScript, which is handled client side, meaning that it's fully editable by the user through the use of a browsers dev tools. The same goes for the auctionId. I would recommend a php session variable logic for the exact same reasons. You can always overwrite the auctionId session variable with another auctionId depending on which auction is "in use".

Another good reason to why setting userId as a session variable, is that you will never have any trouble accessing the variable *anywhere*, as long as you remember to set the following at the very beginning of your PHP files:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

The PHP/SQL syntax for the mysqli_* extension would then be the following:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "auctionsite");
$sql="INSERT INTO auction SET useridhighestbid='$userID'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Let me know if you need anything elaborated, or if you run into any other problems.

Comment: Session can't be used in AJAX. it's not on the same side

Comment: So you can't perform ajax request and get the ID

Comment: Howerver I'd go full php and use $_SESSION like this . check my answer

Comment: @Dice that's my entire point of the post. I do what OP wants, as well as explain why it's a bad practice, and that he should in fact use session variables that he fetches on each individual page WITHOUT the use of AJAX. Nowhere did I ever state that he should parse his session variable through AJAX, because that would literally be contradicting with the point I made in my answer.....................

Answer (score 1):

Send your form to a php script. When the user logs in, retrive his ID from DB and put it in session like this

```
 switch(isset($_POST['login'])):  
        case 'Register':
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['em']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pw']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        // check if the combination fname/lname/email is already used
        include('./Models/log_check.php');
        unset($_SESSION['ID'],$_SESSION['role']);
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
        $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
```

---

So you can use ID in your Model/query:

```
<?php
        /* Jointure sama RDV des vets */
        $query =
        "SELECT
        appointment.start,
        appointment.app_day,
        patients.pet_name,
        patients.breed,
        patients.ID,
        clients.last_name,
        clients.first_name,
        appointment.type,
        appointment.canceled
        FROM appointment
        JOIN patients
        JOIN clients
        WHERE clients.users_ID = patients.owner_ID
        AND patients.ID = appointment.patients_ID
        AND appointment.vets_ID = (SELECT ID FROM vets WHERE users_ID = :ID)
        AND appointment.canceled = 'n'
        AND WEEK(appointment.app_day) = WEEK(:date)
        ORDER BY appointment.app_day,appointment.start";
        $query_params = array(':ID' => $_SESSION['ID'],
                                ':date' => $date);
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    ?>
```

Insert instead of SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You can append the data with the serialize like this in ajax call

```
data: $("#form_id").serialize() + '&xyz=' + xyz
```